# How can I debug google OR tools c++ programs in VS Code or other IDEs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ide, or-tools

For [Google OR tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools), I am trying to compile a c++ example with debug mode (using a flag like `-g` in makefile command `CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -g` ) and then run an example like `or-tools/examples/cpp/integer_programming.cc` in an IDE like VS Code in debug mode. I want to be able to add breakpoints, etc. So far, I have not been able to setup my IDE to do that. I have tried VS Code [Make File Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools&ssr=false#review-details) extension.

Comment: use the CMake build. make is just a shallow layer on top of CMake.

Comment: VS Code is not an IDE, compiling and debugging project using or tools does not seem any different from any other C++ project.

Comment: @LaurentPerron if I understand you are suggesting I build the makefile using cmake. To give you my context I can run `make run path/to/example/example.cc` in the terminal and successfully run `example.cc`. I tried `cmake` extension and it failed. I understand this is more of a cmake, make and vs code question than an or-tools question but your help is very appreciated.

Comment: OrTools does not provide its libraries in Debug format. So, you will not be able to setup breakpoints and step through it in an understandable way. You could set breakpoints in release mode in VS, but in this mode, you cannot examine many variables and states because the compiler will optimize the heck out of it. See https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3903 and https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/2351

Comment: I should add that my comment above applies only in Windows. Under a default linux build as specified in the documents, you can setup breakpoints and step through your code in an understandable debugging sort of way. I have been able to do that using the default CMAKE build from source on both linux and windows.